# Flask application variables are result to empty data structure on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

I have deployed a Flask application on the google app engine exposing various endpoints to the external world.

There are a few global variables including a list. After few hours of adding information to the global variable, it is getting reset to an empty variable and on request through an endpoint, response is null.

Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact behavior may vary depending on your scaling choice but basically App Engine service may spawn new instances if needed to serve more requests or may shut down instances when not needed anymore.

Let's say you have one instance serving with your global variable being updated on that instance. If a new instance is needed, App Engine will spawn a whole new instance from scratch, with a global variable set to default value. Most importantly, one request from a client may reach the first instance but the next request from that same client may reach the second instance, resulting in an inconsistent behavior since your global variable may (most likely) not have the same value on both instances.

In general, you should avoid global variables on distributed systems. I'd recommend to use a persistent storage option like [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview) to store your list, so all App Engine instances will query that store to get the up-to-date, common list. If latency is critical to your app, you may want to cache the value to [Memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/) also for faster retrieval.